# SQL - How to exclude negative values from datediff function

Tags: sql, datediff

How do I exclude all datediff values that are negative from my average statement?

query:

```
select Avg_DayDiff case when Avg_DayDiff > 0

from(

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy) AS Avg_DayDiff

FROM Database1.dbo.tbl_1

where  
        month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
       and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
       and ApprovalRequiredFrom = 'GRM'

       ) temptable
```

My query returns a syntax error from my first line (select statement) I am still learning so any tips are greatly appreciated!

the result I am looking for is to only return datediff if the # > 0, so then I can average it.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please try to use a `where` clause for your main query instead of `case when` in the `select` statement:

```
select Avg_DayDiff 
from(
      SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy) AS Avg_DayDiff
      FROM Database1.dbo.tbl_1
      where  
       month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
       and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
       and ApprovalRequiredFrom = 'GRM'
) temptable
where Avg_DayDiff > 0
```

Comment: You are welcome. I appreciate if you select this answer as the correct answer by clicking the tick on the left. @Pat

Answer (score 2):

You could simply exclude the value  in where  eg

```
    SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy) AS Avg_DayDiff
    FROM Database1.dbo.tbl_1
    where  month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
        and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
           and ApprovalRequiredFrom = 'GRM'
            and  DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use abs() function which returns only positive values.

```
SELECT abs(DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy)) AS Avg_DayDiff
```

The above will be enough to obtain positive values and avoid negative values.

Comment: this actually convert the negatives to positive

Comment: you dont want to consider negative values is that the real theme?